# Multiple pipelines in single gitlab project

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab project with the following format:

```
> folder1
    .gitlab-ci.yml
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

In the root gitlab-ci.yml file, I have the 'version' stage, which I want to be inherited by the sub-pipeline. This is the contents of my root gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
---

stages:
  - version
  - folder1


include:
  - project: remote_group/remote_project
    ref: master
    file:
     - /CI/Build-Code/.gitlab-ci-set-version.yml. //This file has the 'version' job

folder1:
  stage: folder1
  trigger:
    include:
       - project: another_group/another_project
         ref: master
         file: folder1/.gitlab-ci.yml
```

I am getting an error that version was not found in child pipeline. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you give us an example for gitlab-ci.yaml in folder1?